# Enumeration horizontally

Tags: enumerate

How do I make the enumeration environment to appear in an horizontal fashion with the numbers replaced as a) b) c) d). I hope an MWE is not required for this because I have no idea about it.

Comment: Both `enumitem` and `paralist` provide this. The former is better.

Comment: The answer depends on whether your list will be displayed on several lines or not. In the former case you may want to have vertical alignment of the labels. The only packages that can do that are `multenum`, with a tabular-like syntax, and `shortlst`, with a list-like syntax.